# Debugging Java application causes high cpu utilization

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, debugging, cpu-usage

When I'm debugging my Java EE application on Weblogic from Eclipse, in some cases just the fact that the debug is connected and enabled, causes high CPU utilization.
The moment that I disconnect from debug port, the CPU utilization drops to normal levels.

What can cause it and how can I solve it?
Thanks!

Update(s):
Java version 1.6.0_45 (64bit)

Comment: Which version of Java do you have?  This shouldn't happen in modern JVMs.

Comment: Yes, it's Java 1.6.0_45.

Comment: java 6 shouldn't be so bad. I assume using Java 7 or Java 8 is not an option.

Comment: Unfortunately your assumption is correct.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with Netbeans? What about jdb? Since you said port, is this a local JVM you're attaching the debugger to?

Comment: I didn't try Netbeans, the definition of the projects is elaborate to recreate on another IDE.

Comment: I didn't try Netbeans, the definition of the projects is too elaborate to recreate on another IDE.
It's remote debug, and it happens, from time to time both on a separate JVM on the same computer running Windows 7 (32bit) and on Linux server (64bit).
The Eclipse itself is running with Java 8 32bit, but I've experienced the same on same and previous versions of Eclipse running with previous versions of Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in java debugging you can do something called method debugging, that type of method debugging severely impacts performance, make sure you didnt accidently added one of those

[eclipse method breakpoints](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-remove_line_breakpoints.htm)

Comment: Thanks, now when searching for method debugging I realize that it's an old and known problem.